# How to check if a script exists and source it if it does

Tags: gdb

I do not see native GDB commands can do this: check if a gdb script file exists, if so, source the file.

Maybe I need to resort to python, but still want to ask here.

The use case is, I am working on several different computing environments, each one has some different GDB setup. I like to add the above to ~/.gdbinit so that even in each environment I have a different GDB script, it is automatically sourced in my ~/.gdbinit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no built-in way to do this.  It can be done via scripting in a couple of different ways.

The classic way is to use `shell` to test the file existence and have it write out a file that then decides what to do.  Something like:

```
(gdb) shell if test -f blah; then echo source blah; fi > /tmp/F
(gdb) source /tmp/F
```

This is pretty ugly, but it would work.

Alternatively you can write a Python command to do this quite easily.  Or you can dig up the Python `ignore-errors` command, and just use `ignore-errors source whatever`.